# Task scheduling (running backup) with taking care of each user's timezone & DST

Tags: android, ios, node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have native Android & iOS apps developed with NodeJS for back-end web services. What I need is ***to backup users' data every midnight***. I know it can be done at back-end with cron but I want backup to be specific to timezones (i.e. backup should happen when its midnight **"in users' region/timezone"**).

What is the best way to do this?

- ***Should scheduler be at front-end?***
  Run a web service at midnight
  Issue with this approach is when app is closed or if phone is turned off
- ***Should scheduler be at back-end?***
  Record each user's timezone in database and use cron jobs for backup
  How to do this considering there could be daylight saving time as well!

**I want specified backup according to each user's timezone!**

So far, I've tried working on back-end as it is most suitable, convenient & having least chances of failure (nothing can be done at front-end if phone is off or out of network reach). I've used  [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) for cron jobs. But I want to know what frequency should I set to run at 00:01 in every timezone, taking care of DST. Hourly frequency can't be setup because some timezones are of 30 minutes (+05:30) some of 15 & some 45 minutes. Also how to backup only those users who belong to that timezone?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) library for this purpose rather than [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron), since the latter doesn't actually handle DST properly (it uses fixed UTC offsets which is not going to work for every timezone).

You can then create a job for each timezone to run backups. This will run each backup at 00:01 in the local timezone incorporating DST changes, if you loop through each user using spec.users you can then backup their data.

```
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;
const parser = require('cron-parser');

const cronExpression = "01 00 * * *";

let users = [ 
    { name: "user 1", timeZone: "America/New_York"},
    { name: "user 2", timeZone: "Europe/Berlin"},
    { name: "user 3", timeZone: "America/New_York"},
    { name: "user 4", timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"},
]

let backUpJobSpecs = users.reduce((jobs, user) => { 
    let job = jobs.find(job => job.timeZone === user.timeZone);
    if (!job) {
        job = { timeZone: user.timeZone, cronExpression, users: []}
        jobs.push(job);
    }
    job.users.push(user);
    return jobs;
}, []);

function startBackupJobs() {
    let timeZones = [...new Set(backUpJobSpecs.map(({timeZone}) => timeZone))];
    let jobs = backUpJobSpecs.map(createJobFromSpec);
    console.log(`startBackupJobs: ${jobs.length} backup job(s) started for ${timeZones.length} timezone(s)...`);
    console.log(`startBackupJobs: Timezone list: ${timeZones.join(", ")}`);
}

function logTimeUntilBackups() {
    console.log(`${'Timezone'.padEnd(21)}${'Users'.padEnd(21)}Next backup (hours)`);
    backUpJobSpecs.forEach(job => console.log(`${job.timeZone.padEnd(20)}`,`${(job.users.length+"").padEnd(20)}`, Math.round((parser.parseExpression(cronExpression, { tz: job.timeZone }).next().getTime()  - new Date().getTime() ) / 3600000 )) );
}

function createJobFromSpec(spec) {
    return new CronJob(
        spec.cronExpression,
        () => {
            runBackup(spec)
        },
        null,
        true,
        spec.timeZone
    );
}

function runBackup(spec) {
    console.log(`Backup running now for timezone: ${spec.timeZone}`);
    console.log("Local time: "  + new Date().toLocaleString("en", { timeZone: spec.timeZone  }));
    console.log("UTC time: "  + new Date().toISOString());
}

startBackupJobs();
logTimeUntilBackups();
setInterval(logTimeUntilBackups, 60000);
```

Comment: I think separate job for each user would result in too many jobs running together which might not be best for server. Can't it be optimized by running cron at 00:01 in each & every timezone & combine users belonging to that timezone together?

Comment: Certainly, that was actually my next suggestion, I'll update the answer!

Comment: I've updated so we'll run a job per timezone. Each spec object has a list of the users for that timezone.

Comment: How can I get timezone for users in name format like **America/New_York** unlike GMT format as **-04:00** ? Because mobile gives latter format!

Comment: Ah yes, that's tricky. The problem is that it is difficult to convert from a UTC offset to a timezone id, since the UTC offset is ambiguous (there could be many timezone ids with the same UTC offset). The GMT format doesn't give us enough data to work with (e.g. the Daylight Saving Time offsets and transition times). You could convert to a generic timezone id, e.g. "Etc/GMT+5" (which is equivalent to Eastern Standard Time). The risk there is that you might run the backup an hour late or an hour early, though I wouldn't think that is a huge issue.

Comment: Have you tried: 

TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println("TimeZone   "+tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)+" Timezon id :: " +tz.getID()); to get timezone id? (Android)

Comment: no I haven't tried that one. I will give it a try. Thanks